# Explicit typing - Array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

In the below syntax,

```
interface IPerson{
    firstName: string;
    lastName?: string;
}

const personList = [
    "p1": {firstName: "F1", lastName: "L1"},
    "p2": {firstName: "F2"},
    "p3": {firstName: "F3"}
];

// or

const personList = [
    {"p1": {firstName: "F1", lastName: "L1"}},
    {"p2": {firstName: "F2"}},
    {"p3": {firstName: "F3"}}
];
```

`personList` is an array of key:value pairs, where key is of type `string` and value is of type `IPerson`

**Edit:**

Below syntax allows more than one key:value pair at an index of an array

```
const personList:{[key:string]:IPerson}[] = [
    {
     "p1": {firstName: "F1", lastName: "L1"},
     "p2": {firstName: "F1", lastName: "L1"}   
    },
    {"p2": {firstName: "F2"}},
    {"p3": {firstName: "F3"}}
];
```

How to explicitly type `personList`?

Comment: First example of `const personList` is not a valid JS array.

Comment: @BlackBeard you are right. thank you

Comment: Both posted answers are as good as you're going to get, there's no way in the type system to constrain an object to a single property.

Answer (score 3):

```
const personList: { [key: string]: IPerson }[]  = [
    {"p1": {firstName: "F1", lastName: "L1"}},
    {"p2": {firstName: "F2"}},
    {"p3": {firstName: "F3"}}
];
```

Define it as an array of objects whose key is a string and whose value is of type `IPerson`

Comment: There is a problem with your syntax. Edited

Answer (score 1):

An index type cannot be constrained to a single property, so both the posted answers are probably as good as you'll get.

As an alternative you could use a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple):

```
const personList: [string, IPerson][] = [
    ["p1", { firstName: "F1", lastName: "L1" }],
    ["p2", { firstName: "F2"}],
    ["p3", { firstName: "F3" }]
];
```

This will constrain each element of the array to an array of `[string, IPerson]`:

```
personList.forEach(item => {
    const [key, person] = item;
    // `key` is type string (p1, p2, p3...)
    // `person` is type IPerson
});
```

Comment: Can't I have first element as key?`let personList: [[id: string], IPerson][] = []` Because having keys in `personList` is most important

Comment: No. Array uses index, object uses keys.

Comment: you mean tuple is a n element array?

Comment: Basically, yes, it describes an array with known types at explicit indices.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map interface:

```
interface Map<T> {
    [K: string]: T;
}

const personList: Map<IPerson> = [];
```

Comment: Your syntax also has same problem. Query already edited. `map<IPerson>[]` does not work